# Tcl, if not not working

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to do a If not on a string match with Tcl. However, when I expect it not to match, it seems to be matching because when it shouldn't match it continues to "I don't want it to do this". Hope this makes sense. Inside the log.text file, it should contain, "This is a String."

```
set var1 "String"
set file [open "log.text" r]

while {[gets $file data] != -1} {
   if {![string match *[string toupper $var1]* [string toupper $data]]} {
       *I don't want it to do this
   }
}
```

Comment: Does it match when you expect it to match?

Comment: *when it shouldn't match it continues to "FAIL did not match"* Isn't it then working correctly?

Comment: Considering the title of the question, you seem to be confused by double negatives.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is if it does not match the string then fail the test.

Comment: Can you include an example input to the question, and describe what precisely you expect to happen for that input, and what happens instead?

Comment: Yes please provide some input, even if it's just 3 lines

Comment: What do you mean by input?

Comment: The contents of the file `log.text`.

Comment: It contains, "This is a String.".

Comment: And what should the program do based on this input file? Should it say "FAIL did not match" or should it do nothing?

Comment: It should do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to work fine:

```
$ cat log.text
This is a String
this line does not match
```

```
$ tclsh <<'END'
set var1 "String"
set file [open "log.text" r]

while {[gets $file data] != -1} {
   if {![string match -nocase *$var1* $data]} {
        puts "$data: does not match $var1"
   }                                      
}   
END
```

outputs

```
this line does not match: does not match String
```

---

Ah, now you have clearly stated what you want: does the string exist **in the file**, yes or no.  Here are some ways to accomplish that:

1. read the entire file, and string match against that.

   ```
   set file [open log.text r]
   set contents [read -nonewline $file]
   close $file
   set pattern_exists [string match -nocase *$var1* $contents]
   if {$pattern_exists} {puts "$var1 found in file"}
   ```
2. read the file line-by-line until the pattern is found

   ```
   set pattern_exists false
   set file [open log.text r]
   while {[gets $file line] != -1} {
       if {[string match -nocase *$var1* $line]} {
           set pattern_exists true
           break
       }
   }
   close $file
   if {$pattern_exists} {puts "$var1 found in file"}
   ```
3. call out to grep to do the heavy lifting: grep exits with non-zero status when the pattern is not found, and `exec` thinks a non-zero exit status is an exception (see https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm#M27)

   ```
   try {
       exec grep -qi $var1 log.text
       set pattern_exists true
   } on error {e} {
       set pattern_exists false
   }
   if {$pattern_exists} {puts "$var1 found in file"}
   ```

Comment: What happens if you change the content of log.text to "This is a line."?

Comment: But I want it to do nothing though. I don't want it to print that puts line.

Comment: As I said, you might be confused by double negative logic. Does the program work as you expect if you simply invert the condition by removing the `!`?

Comment: Yes the program works if I remove the "!". With that remove, it'll print the puts line in this code.

Comment: @Channing, my input file has 2 lines, and the output has 1 line. For the line that matches $var1, no output. For the line that does not match $var1, yes output. What is the confusion?

Comment: I'm confused because that is not what I'm hoping to do. What I'm hoping to do is, find a string in a file, if the string is in the file, exit the if statement. I'm sorry I'm such a newbie at this.

Answer (score 0):

The code *as you wrote it* works… but I'm guessing it is a proxy for something else. If you are looking to see if an *arbitrary* string exists as a substring of a line, you are better off using `string first` instead of `string match`, since the latter has a few metacharacters (especially `[` and `]`, which denote a set of characters) that can cause problems if you're not expecting them.

Try:

```
if {[string first [string toupper $var1] [string toupper $data]] >= 0} {
    # The substring was there...
}
```

Alternatively, apply relevant backslash quoting when building your search pattern (possibly with `string map`) or use `regexp`, which has a useful find-a-literal mode:

```
if {[regexp -nocase ***=$var1 $data]} {
    # The substring was there...
}
```

The `***=` means “the rest of this pattern is a literal string to match” and we can pass `-nocase` as an option to allow us to not need to use `string toupper`.

Comment: Thank you Donal for your help.